# Hiding an element by geolocation on Shopify Checkout page without inline script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to use an API call to IPstack in order to hide the express payment options for customers coming from Japan (JP). It worked a few times when testing via browser stack, but now my api call is getting the following consolve log error 'because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: cdn.shopify.com cdn.shopifycdn.net cdn.shopifycloud.com app.shopify.com'. Does anyone know any other way to hide elements by geolocation on the shopify checkout.liquid page?

```
<div class ="alt-payments">{{ alternative_payment_methods }}</div>
            <script>
              jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=API_ACCESS_KEY&fields=country_code',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(location) {
                    // If the visitor is browsing from JP.
                    if (location.country_code === 'JP') {
                    // display none express payments.
                    jQuery('.alt-payments').css('display','none');
                    }
                }
                } );
            </script>
```

Comment: Is the store is Shopify plus or any custom or 3rd party that accessing the checkout pages into Shopify?

Comment: the store is shopify plus - i'm trying to use the results of an API call to IPstack to return a value for the customers country code to check against the condition JP and use jquery to hide the express checkout payment methods with display none of the condition is true.

Comment: I think over the Shopify plus you develop the logic based on the country over the previous steps like address or shipping details, no need rely on 3rd party request?

Comment: using the shopify variables for address country would not work as a solution because we need to hide the express payment methods before customers would begin to input their address into the regular checkout fields. We can't allow any customers from Japan to use the express checkout methods which are selected before they enter shipping info.

Comment: you need to check the location on the homepage or collection or any other page and save the value to local storage and use it over the checkout page, due to security issues Shopify might doesn't allow any 3rd party over the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Shopify Scripts, since you're on Plus. Payments come after Shipping anyway. So you have the address BEFORE payments. Unless you are truly doing something weird. A normal Plus checkout would just check the address, then use a script to hide a payment method you don't like. That is the whole point of Plus.

Comment: that would be the case David, except that express checkout methods are offered before a customer enters their address to the regular shopify checkout flow. The problem is that customers who choose to checkout with an express method (such as ApplePay or Paypal) can enter a shipping address that is not able to be validated through the Shopify Checkout API because these are independently hosted third-party checkouts, so our APAC customers who choose an express method (Paypal or ApplePay) are able to input invalid non-latin characters for their shipping address and can not be shipped.

Comment: Makes no sense to me. The whole point of using Apple Pay or Paypal is so you never have to provide your address. There is no Express in Express payments if I have to actually do anything except push a single button. Sounds like you have deeper problems than I thought though.. tough and too bad!